# Automatically give UWP apps permission from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, uwp, windows-10

I am trying to contribute to [this](https://github.com/files-community/files-uwp) project, which is an UWP file explorer app. This app uses `broadFileSystemAccess` permission for which Windows doesn't ask user when app is launched. User has to go to settings and explicitly allow this app for storage access. This really makes debugging painful as whenever I deploy the app, I have to give the app storage permission, launch the app and then attach debugger. Is there any way I can give this app necessary permissions just after deployment and before debugging starts?? Any form of powershell scripts that I can run as a post deployment task??

Comment: This doesn't defeat the UWP sand-boxing purpose in any way, All I want is powershell script to give permission to uwp app from Visual Studio and this will be great for development purposes and normal users don't have to bother with this in any way.

Comment: You mean bad instead of mad?? Yes, I am not talking about after package deployed and prior to debug.

Comment: _"whenever I deploy the app"_ - deploy to where? Local? Remote machine for debugging?  I just did a test just now and the **first** time I built the app, I natuarally had to enable **File System** in **Privacy** but for subsequent builds I did not.  Even a rebuild worked fine - it remembered the setting.  You might be able to do a dodgy _sendkeys_ to Control Panel in the same way people change their default web browser thus overriding Group Policy defaults.  Crude but it works

Comment: Deploying to my local machine. For me its strange sometimes it remembers permission while sometimes it doesn't and I always have to check. Also, in you test, did you just build or after building you deployed the app, also when you tried subsequent build or rebuild did you make any changes to code or kept the code same??

Comment: I only chose to build but I noticed it also appeared in **Privacy** _**and**_ the **Start** menu so I guess there is some form of deployment happening on my local machine.  I built a few times and an additional re-build and it seemed to remember my settings.  I might be just lucky though?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Windows 10 2004, you no longer need to give file permissions to UWP apps that include a FullTrust process.

Answer (score 1):

Due to this capability is restricted and sensitive, so user has to turn it on manually. See [Accessing additional locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations).

But you can help to ask this permission.

```
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

Or launch the url using code

```
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync("ms-settings:privacy-broadfilesystemaccess");
```

Comment: If you took time to look at the code, you will see this has been already implemented. And if you have taken the time to actually read the question and the immediate comment to my question you will see I am asking for giving the app permission in my own machine from VS studio (for debugging purposes) which doesn't sound unreasonable to me or many other developers. As for the impossible part I have seen many people in the past who think they know everything and answered me the task is impossible but I have found the answer after doing some painful research so we will see about that.